# A deck of 20 cards is randomly shuffled. What is the probability that the last three cards selected are all odd-numbered cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

**A deck of 20 cards numbered 1, 2, ..., 20 is randomly shuffled. The cards are randomly selected one at a time without replacement, until all 20 have been selected. What is the probability that the last three cards selected are all odd-numbered cards?**

My attempt to solve this would be that there are total of 10 odd numbered cards. For card 1 to be chose, it would be 1/17 as the three odd number cards are reserved.

So it would be 1/17 * 1/16 * 1/15....

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

By symmetry,
P(last 3 cards are odd numbered) = P(first 3 cards are odd numbered)

You should be able to take it from there !

### PS:

I thought this much of a hint was enough, but I see a lot of comments, so for completeness I am giving the answer here. There will be $10$ odd and $10$ even numbers from $1$ through $20$, so

P(last 3 cards are odd numbered) = P(first 3 cards are odd numbered) $= \dfrac{10}{20}\cdot\dfrac9{19}\cdot\dfrac8{18}$

Comment: Is it like 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 for the first three cards and then continue on 1/17 * 1/16 ... * 1/1 for the probability of first three cards being odd numbered?

Comment: Once you have got the first three odd numbered cards, you don't care what the remaining cards are !

Comment: @madmaximille Notice that $10$ of the $20$ cards are odd-numbered.

Comment: So just this 1/10 * 1/9 * 1/8 for probability for the first three cards to be odd numbered?

Comment: @madmaximille, no, it is $\frac{10}{20}\cdot\frac{9}{19}\cdot \frac{8}{18}$.

Comment: Then, for the last three cards to be odd numbered, shouldn't they be dependent on the first 17 cards as well?

Comment: They are, but we have avoided a cumbersome computation by taking advantage of symmetry,